# Render list in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and was trying to render a todo-list in an exercise. My Code looks like this:

**Todo** Component

```
export default function Todo(props) {
    return {props.list.map(todo => <li>{todo}</li>)};
}
```

**App** Component

```
import Todo from './Todo';

const DUMMY_TODOS = [
    'Learn React',
    'Practice React',
    'Profit!'
];

export default function App() {
    return (
        <ul>
          <Todo list={DUMMY_TODOS}/>
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Since my code didn't work, I tried with the following code:

**Todo** Component

```
export default function Todo(props) {
    return <ul>{props.list.map(todo => <li>{todo}</li>)}</ul>;
}
```

**App** Component

```
import Todo from './Todo';

const DUMMY_TODOS = [
    'Learn React',
    'Practice React',
    'Profit!'
];

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Todo list={DUMMY_TODOS}/>
    );
}
```

And this worked.

For me, both of them are basically the same thing. So I don't get it why the first solution didn't work and the second did. Does anyone know the reason here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first attempt you are trying to return an array of JSX elements from your `<Todo />` component. This is not allowed, all JSX returned elements must have a single parent (which is why your second attempt worked). Therefore, the solution is to wrap your elements in a fragment (`<>{...}</>`) this gives the array a parent. Furthermore, you must specify a unique `key` prop for each item in a rendered array.

```js
const DUMMY_TODOS = [
  'Learn React',
  'Practice React',
  'Profit!'
];

function App() {
  return (
      <ul>
        <Todo list={DUMMY_TODOS}/>
      </ul>
  );
}

function Todo(props) {
  return <React.Fragment>
    {props.list.map(todo => <li key={todo}>{todo}</li>)}
  </React.Fragment>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```